# Eclipse crash EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in libapr

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse always crashes when I import a project on a disk or from the svn, but I can open it without code. I have repeatly installed Java and reset envionment variables, but it didn't work at all.
Here is the error log.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0b80834c, pid=8696, tid=7516
#
# JRE version: 6.0_43-b01
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libapr-1.dll+0x834c]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x066d9000):  JavaThread "Worker-10" [_thread_in_native, id=7516, stack(0x0b2e0000,0x0b3e0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x011b2a68, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x0b3d88f8, EBP=0x0b3d8904, ESI=0x0056ef70, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x0b80834c, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0b3d88f8)
0x0b3d88f8:   00000000 0056ef70 011b2a68 0b3da930
0x0b3d8908:   0b7a1f32 0b3da92c 011b2a68 00000000
0x0b3d8918:   00000000 00000000 0056ef70 011b2a68
0x0b3d8928:   00000000 011b2a68 00000000 011b2a68
0x0b3d8938:   011b2b08 0bd98461 011b2a68 00000010
0x0b3d8948:   0b790000 0bd911f2 011b2a68 011b2b08
0x0b3d8958:   0bd91210 0bd98570 011b2a68 011b2ab8
0x0b3d8968:   011b2a68 011b2a68 00000001 003a0043 

Instructions: (pc=0x0b80834c)
0x0b80832c:   8b c1 8b 4d 10 85 c9 75 0a 85 c0 74 06 8b 50 20
0x0b80833c:   89 55 10 53 8b 5d 14 56 57 85 db 75 03 8b 58 18
0x0b80834c:   8b 03 bf 01 00 00 00 3b c7 0f 82 1d 01 00 00 8b
0x0b80835c:   43 0c 85 c0 74 06 50 e8 d8 f0 ff ff 8b 73 18 8b 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x011b2a68 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0b3d88f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x066d9000
EBP=0x0b3d8904 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x066d9000
ESI=0x0056ef70 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0b2e0000,0x0b3e0000],  sp=0x0b3d88f8,  free space=994k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libapr-1.dll+0x834c]  apr_pool_create_ex+0x3c
C  [libapriconv-1.dll+0x1f32]  apr_iconv_mod_load+0x1b2
C  [libapriconv-1.dll+0x1da4]  apr_iconv_mod_load+0x24
C  [_tbl_simple.so+0x123b]
C  [_tbl_simple.so+0x11c4]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.tigris.subversion.javahl.SVNClient.checkout(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/Revision;Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/Revision;ZZ)J+0
j  org.tigris.subversion.javahl.SVNClient.checkout(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/Revision;Z)J+8
j  org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.checkout(Lorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/SVNUrl;Ljava/io/File;Lorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/SVNRevision;Z)V+101
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.commands.CheckoutCommand.checkoutProject(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;Lorg/tigris/subversion/subclipse/core/ISVNRemoteFolder;Lorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/ISVNClientAdapter;Ljava/io/File;)V+50
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.commands.CheckoutCommand.basicRun(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Lorg/tigris/subversion/subclipse/core/ISVNRemoteFolder;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+384
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.commands.CheckoutCommand$1.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+13
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNProviderPlugin$6.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+10
j  org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspaceRunnable;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/ISchedulingRule;ILorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+80
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.SVNProviderPlugin.run(Lorg/tigris/subversion/subclipse/core/ISVNRunnable;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/ISchedulingRule;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+20
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.commands.CheckoutCommand.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+41
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.CheckoutAsProjectOperation.execute([Lorg/tigris/subversion/subclipse/core/ISVNRemoteFolder;[Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+39
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.CheckoutAsProjectOperation.execute(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+133
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.operations.SVNOperation.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+35
j  org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext.run(Lorg/eclipse/jface/operation/IRunnableWithProgress;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus;+2
j  org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext$ResourceJob.runInWorkspace(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus;+9
j  org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus;+37
j  org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run()V+31
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x066db400 JavaThread "Worker-14" [_thread_blocked, id=10160, stack(0x0c770000,0x0c870000)]
  0x066da800 JavaThread "Worker-13" [_thread_blocked, id=9148, stack(0x0c3a0000,0x0c4a0000)]
  0x066d8800 JavaThread "Worker-12" [_thread_blocked, id=2508, stack(0x0c2a0000,0x0c3a0000)]
  0x066d7c00 JavaThread "Worker-11" [_thread_blocked, id=9444, stack(0x0a5e0000,0x0a6e0000)]
=>0x066d9000 JavaThread "Worker-10" [_thread_in_native, id=7516, stack(0x0b2e0000,0x0b3e0000)]
  0x066dc000 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9760, stack(0x0bdd0000,0x0bed0000)]
  0x066da400 JavaThread "Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=1848, stack(0x0bc80000,0x0bd80000)]
  0x066db000 JavaThread "com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7468, stack(0x0ba80000,0x0bb80000)]
  0x066d9c00 JavaThread "16351584@qtp-881692-1 - Acceptor0 SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:50313" [_thread_in_native, id=4972, stack(0x0cc70000,0x0cd70000)]
  0x066d9400 JavaThread "32932074@qtp-881692-0" [_thread_blocked, id=4288, stack(0x0cb70000,0x0cc70000)]
  0x066d7800 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8264, stack(0x0b980000,0x0ba80000)]
  0x066d7000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7976, stack(0x0b3e0000,0x0b4e0000)]
  0x06623800 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4548, stack(0x0afe0000,0x0b0e0000)]
  0x06512000 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4884, stack(0x0a6e0000,0x0a7e0000)]
  0x099b8c00 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=9672, stack(0x0a170000,0x0a270000)]
  0x099e8c00 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1448, stack(0x0a070000,0x0a170000)]
  0x0999e800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9840, stack(0x09f70000,0x0a070000)]
  0x099ec800 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4772, stack(0x09e70000,0x09f70000)]
  0x099ea800 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4004, stack(0x09d70000,0x09e70000)]
  0x09957000 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=9044, stack(0x09c70000,0x09d70000)]
  0x05e55000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8912, stack(0x09650000,0x09750000)]
  0x05e30000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1508, stack(0x09550000,0x09650000)]
  0x05e29c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=852, stack(0x09450000,0x09550000)]
  0x05e26c00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10004, stack(0x09350000,0x09450000)]
  0x05e1c800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6172, stack(0x09250000,0x09350000)]
  0x05e17c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9952, stack(0x09150000,0x09250000)]
  0x04029800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9292, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

Other Threads:
  0x05e13c00 VMThread [stack: 0x09050000,0x09150000] [id=2740]
  0x05e72800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x09750000,0x09850000] [id=7880]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 39488K, used 15546K [0x104e0000, 0x12fb0000, 0x1af80000)
  eden space 35136K,  44% used [0x104e0000, 0x1140eb18, 0x12730000)
  from space 4352K,   0% used [0x12730000, 0x12730000, 0x12b70000)
  to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x12b70000, 0x12b70000, 0x12fb0000)
 tenured generation   total 87424K, used 39620K [0x1af80000, 0x204e0000, 0x304e0000)
   the space 87424K,  45% used [0x1af80000, 0x1d631308, 0x1d631400, 0x204e0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 71424K, used 71321K [0x304e0000, 0x34aa0000, 0x404e0000)
   the space 71424K,  99% used [0x304e0000, 0x34a866c8, 0x34a86800, 0x34aa0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x07050000, 0x07550000, 0x09050000)
 total_blobs=2182 nmethods=1963 adapters=151 free_code_cache=28323584 largest_free_block=256

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00417000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\eclipse.exe
0x776b0000 - 0x777ec000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x75b40000 - 0x75c14000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75af0000 - 0x75b3b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x77810000 - 0x778d9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x77330000 - 0x7737e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76c20000 - 0x76c2a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x75c70000 - 0x75d0d000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x76c30000 - 0x76cdc000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x70880000 - 0x70904000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5\COMCTL32.dll
0x76ce0000 - 0x76d80000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x770a0000 - 0x770b9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x77150000 - 0x771f2000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77380000 - 0x7739f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76e00000 - 0x76ecc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x72000000 - 0x7200d000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502\eclipse_1406.dll
0x74d00000 - 0x74d09000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x741b0000 - 0x741f0000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x75770000 - 0x757bc000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x10000000 - 0x104de000     C:\Windows\system32\SOGOUPY.IME
0x731b0000 - 0x731b5000     C:\Windows\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x77290000 - 0x772c5000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x77090000 - 0x77096000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x76ed0000 - 0x76f27000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x73250000 - 0x7328c000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEACC.dll
0x76f30000 - 0x7708c000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x74ab0000 - 0x74ad1000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x75c20000 - 0x75c65000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x75eb0000 - 0x76afa000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x757c0000 - 0x757cc000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x040b0000 - 0x0418d000     C:\Program Files\SogouInput\7.7.0.6390\Resource.dll
0x6dfd0000 - 0x6e157000     C:\Program Files\SogouInput\Components\PicFace\1.0.0.1356\PicFace.dll
0x77200000 - 0x7728f000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x73790000 - 0x737a3000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x777f0000 - 0x777f5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x75840000 - 0x7584b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x6d8c0000 - 0x6db70000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x74c00000 - 0x74c32000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x7c360000 - 0x7c3b6000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR71.dll
0x6d870000 - 0x6d87c000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3d0000 - 0x6d3ef000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d8b0000 - 0x6d8bf000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x752b0000 - 0x752c6000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x75050000 - 0x7508b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x74e90000 - 0x74ea7000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x6d6b0000 - 0x6d6c3000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\jre\bin\net.dll
0x75270000 - 0x752ac000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x75260000 - 0x75266000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x73dc0000 - 0x73dd0000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x71680000 - 0x71690000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x71660000 - 0x71672000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x75130000 - 0x75174000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x71650000 - 0x71658000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x74bb0000 - 0x74bb5000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x74ce0000 - 0x74cfc000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x74cd0000 - 0x74cd7000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x74b70000 - 0x74b76000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x73af0000 - 0x73b28000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6d6d0000 - 0x6d6d9000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x09b00000 - 0x09b6e000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\590\1\.cp\swt-win32-3735.dll
0x76d80000 - 0x76dfb000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x74230000 - 0x743ce000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x76b00000 - 0x76c1b000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x77800000 - 0x77803000     C:\Windows\system32\Normaliz.dll
0x773a0000 - 0x7755b000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x77560000 - 0x7767a000     C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
0x75980000 - 0x75aa0000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x758b0000 - 0x758bc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x744f0000 - 0x745e5000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x770c0000 - 0x77143000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x6eab0000 - 0x6eab9000     C:\Windows\system32\LINKINFO.dll
0x09b70000 - 0x09b8d000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\590\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-3735.dll
0x74020000 - 0x741b0000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.18455_none_72d576ad8665e853\gdiplus.dll
0x735e0000 - 0x73710000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x06220000 - 0x0622e000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\66\1\.cp\os\win32\x86\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x6eda0000 - 0x6ef0f000     C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
0x73e70000 - 0x73e9f000     C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
0x73ea0000 - 0x73f52000     C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
0x6ec80000 - 0x6ec8f000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\69\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x713f0000 - 0x71448000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x713a0000 - 0x713ef000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x74b80000 - 0x74b8d000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x74b90000 - 0x74ba2000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x75830000 - 0x7583e000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x737c0000 - 0x737ee000     C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
0x75d10000 - 0x75ead000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75ac0000 - 0x75ae7000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x75aa0000 - 0x75ab2000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x6deb0000 - 0x6df20000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x755a0000 - 0x755b9000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x6ec40000 - 0x6ec4b000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x73cc0000 - 0x73cca000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x0b130000 - 0x0b13e000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseStub.dll
0x0c4a0000 - 0x0c56a000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseSVN.dll
0x6ef20000 - 0x6ef25000     C:\Windows\system32\SHFOLDER.dll
0x0b160000 - 0x0b182000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libapr_tsvn.dll
0x73290000 - 0x73333000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCR90.dll
0x0c570000 - 0x0c59f000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libaprutil_tsvn.dll
0x0c5a0000 - 0x0c5b2000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\intl3_tsvn.dll
0x71730000 - 0x717be000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCP90.dll
0x74bd0000 - 0x74bd9000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x703c0000 - 0x703cc000     C:\Windows\system32\mssprxy.dll
0x0bd90000 - 0x0bdb1000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\778\1\.cp\libapr.dll
0x0bdc0000 - 0x0bdc9000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\778\1\.cp\libapriconv.dll
0x0d070000 - 0x0d176000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\778\1\.cp\libeay32.dll
0x716b0000 - 0x716b7000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x0bed0000 - 0x0bf7d000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\778\1\.cp\libdb43.dll
0x5c540000 - 0x5c5a6000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP60.dll
0x0c5f0000 - 0x0c622000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\778\1\.cp\ssleay32.dll
0x0c630000 - 0x0c659000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\778\1\.cp\libaprutil.dll
0x0d180000 - 0x0d192000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\778\1\.cp\intl3_svn.dll
0x0e340000 - 0x0e438000     D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\778\1\.cp\libsvnjavahl-1.dll
0x0b790000 - 0x0b795000     C:\Program Files\Subversion\iconv\_tbl_simple.so
0x0b7a0000 - 0x0b7a9000     C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\libapriconv-1.dll
0x0b800000 - 0x0b823000     C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\libapr-1.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\jre\lib\rt.jar;.;
PATH=D:/eclipse3.7/eclipse/jre/bin/client;D:/eclipse3.7/eclipse/jre/bin;D:/eclipse3.7/eclipse/jre/lib/i386;.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\bin;F:\oracleXE\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin;;;C:\Program Files\dwcom;;D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse;
USERNAME=ZZ
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 2992540k(1059792k free), swap 5983328k(3560956k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.14-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_43-b01), built on Mar  1 2013 02:51:23 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Fri Sep 11 14:21:18 2015
elapsed time: 948 seconds
```

Comment: Search at http://bugs.java.com/ or create a new bugreport at oracle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I result the problem! It just need to change one Variable 'APR_ICONV_PATH' to 'APR_ICONV1_PATH'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try upgrading to the newest Eclipse version and see if it still happens there. From the crash log, it appears that you are using Eclipse 3.7, which is old. The [current version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) at the time of writing is **4.5** (Mars). There's usually no reason to stay with an old IDE version. Also, your Eclipse seems to be using a packaged JRE (`D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll`), so reinstalling your system JRE might not affect the issue at all.

If this doesn't help, try swapping the SVN provider you are using - right now the log says you are using Subclipse by Tigris, which is where the crash appears to happen, but there's also a viable alternative called [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/).

SVN providers can be switched in a blank Eclipse, which you said you are able to start. Just follow the installation instructions from that plugin and make sure you remove the other provider beforehand. To be completely safe, backup your Eclipse installation first.

If there are any open questions, please feel free to ask. Good luck!

Comment: To tell you the truth,evervthing is ok before 5 days ago.All of my colleagues using Eclipse 3.7 which is binding the same plugins.I did not do anything except an unexpected power off,then it failed.

Comment: JRE (D:\eclipse3.7\eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll), it's one solution what i have tried,but it did not worked at all.By the way,not only the svn povider,but also it  crashed where  i imported one projec i used before ,so i think it is  about someting other.                                           Thank you very much!

Comment: @TY.Mikee Have you tried cloning a coworkers Eclipse to your machine? That power-off probably corrupted some of the libs involved so we need to find out where the problem is. If a cloned Eclipse shows the same crashes, take a good look at the log and replace the dlls where the crashes happen with those from a colleague's machine (given that the OS and architecture (bitness) are the same).

Comment: I result the problem!  I knew that my several colleagues had met this problem before when I asked for a clone.It just need to change one Variable 'APR_ICONV_PATH' to 'APR_ICONV1_PATH'.Thany you all the same!

Comment: @TY.Mikee Great, I'm happy for you. I've never heard about that variable, I'm afraid. 

Instead of editing the solution into your question, convention is that you post an answer with the solution yourself, and mark it as accepted answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: This is my first time to ask a question here,in fact.Thank you for the hint.;)

Comment: @TY.Mikee Yes, I could tell from your profile :) Welcome to StackOverflow! If you liked the service, tell all your friends about us. You might also be interested in taking a look at the [tour].

Comment: Surprise！Are you a founder of the site?What an hornor!I'm wondering if  you made the edit suggested .Yes, I will tell all my friends.Be happy!

Comment: @TY.Mikee Hah, no, I'm not a founder. I'm just your friendly community representative. The StackExchange network (StackOverflow and all its sister sites) is all about the community, you know. I'm pretty sure the founders would agree that without the community, StackExchange is nothing. Yes, I made the suggested edit and removed the solution you found from your question. If you have any questions about the site left, please feel free to ask me or take a look at the [tour] and [help]. When you reach 20 reputation score, you can also go to the sites' chat rooms and ask your questions there.